# How do i display a UWP-App in a Webview in another UWP-App (under Windows 10)?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

(Sorry for my bad english)

So im currently trying to Display a Win App in another Windows App, i thought the best way to do that would be to work with WebView Class.

Ive been searching the through many websites to find some hints to solve this for myself but i couldn't find any Info related to that.
I think that the file Package.appxmanifest might be necessary but i dont know how to use this File correctly.

```
    <Grid>
        <WebView HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="webView1" Height="382" Width="910" Source="ms-windows-store:" Margin="48,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
```

that gives me an error for the entered Source.

In the End i want to Display (lets say Windows Store) the App and if possible be able to Scroll/write and press on button to load another page.

Answer (score 1):

Your request goes beyond the limitations of UWP, so you may possibly try to do something similar with WPF if that is acceptable, otherwise your project is not feasible.